# Ошибка при входе на сайт

Tags: php

Я поставил движок на сайт :

```
<?php
include ('/core.php');
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'default';
switch ($page) {
   case ('register'):
        include ('/style/register.php');   
        break;
   default :
        include ('/style/main.php');
        break;
}
?>
```

Вот, и при входе на сайт выбивает ошибку:

*Удаленный сервер или файл не найден*
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

Comment: то что Главная и регистрация лежит в папке Стайл , это все правильно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Вы используете абсолютные пути от корня файловой системы, в этом видимо и ошибка.

Если я прав, то стоит добавить точку перед адресами файлов, и должно заработать.

2) Не хватает закрытия скобки:

Вместо: `$page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'default';`
Надо: `$page = (isset($_GET['page'])`  **`)`**  `?$_GET['page']:'default';`

Comment: спасибо, вы как всегда правы =)

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут на ум может прийти только одно - адрес к файлу не верен. Попробуйте задать абсолютный путь.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужен полный путь до файлов сайта (можно попробовать).
2. Это думаю не в тему,а права "нового движка" повзоляют его работу? Попробуйте 777.
3. Проверьте наличие и содержание всех остальных файлов.