# Не работает движок

Tags: php

У меня стоит движок:

```
<?php
include ('/core.php');
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'default';
switch ($page) {
   case ('register'):
        include ('/style/register.php');   
        break;
   default :
        include ('/style/index.php');
        break;
}
?>
```

Но как бы я не пробовал его настроить, сайт не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать. и еще, то что файлы лежат в style это все верно!

Comment: 1. Что значит сайт не находит? Что не находит?
2. `include ('/core.php');` - это не верно, нужно писать что-то типа:

    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core.php');

Comment: Когда я ввожу адрес сайта то пишет: Внутренняя ошибка сайта

Comment: @Prikol, А в лог заглянуть? Когда возникает "Внутренняя ошибка сайта", сервер (apache2, к примеру) пишет ошибку в лог-файл.

Comment: У меня не пишет.

Comment: В чем проблема? Сделайте чтобы писались.

Comment: а как это сделать ?=)

Comment: Забей на сайты. Займись дизайном!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('RD', dirname(__FILE__));
include (RD . '/core.php');
```

Как вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не понятен, но попробую:

У Вас есть строчка:

```
include ('/core.php');
```

Насколько я знаю, это значит файл должен лежать в самом корне, имеется ввиду не корне сайта!)

Попробуйте исправить так:

```
include ('./core.php');
```

С относительными путями всегда неразбериха. Удачи.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вы повторяете [свой-же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/48318/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) вопрос???

Писать надо без ошибок:

```
$page = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 'default';
```

Но смысла в этой строчке нет, т.к. в `switch` обработчик `default` сработает всё-равно
Поэтому я-бы написал так:

```
<?php
  include ('./core.php');
  switch ( $_GET['page'] ) {
   case ('register'):
    include ('./style/register.php');   
   break;
   default:
    include ('./style/index.php');
  }
?>
```